# Using the context API in Next.js

Tags: next.js, react-context

I'm building a simple Next.js website that consumes the spacex graphql API, using apollo as a client. I'm trying to make an api call, save the returned data to state and then set that state as context.
Before I save the data to state however, I wanted to check that my context provider was actually providing context to the app, so I simply passed the string 'test' as context.
However, up[on trying to extract this context in antoher component, I got the following error:

> Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/"

My project is set up as follows, and I'm thinking I may have put the context file in the wrong place:

```
pages
 -api
 -items
    -_app.js
    -index.js
public
styles
next.config.js
spacexContext.js
```

Here's the rest of my app:

**spaceContext.js**

```
import { useState,useEffect,createContext } from 'react'
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client"

export const LaunchContext = createContext()


export const getStaticProps = async () => {

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: 'https://api.spacex.land/graphql/',
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  })

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query GetLaunches {
        launchesPast(limit: 10) {
          id
          mission_name
          launch_date_local
          launch_site {
            site_name_long
          }
          links {
            article_link
            video_link
            mission_patch
          }
          rocket {
            rocket_name
          }
        }
      }
    `
  });

  return {
    props: {
      launches: data.launchesPast
    }
  }
}

const LaunchContextProvider = (props) => {

    return(
        <LaunchContext.Provider value = 'test'>
            {props.children}
        </LaunchContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default LaunchContextProvider
```

**_app.js**

```
import LaunchContextProvider from '../spacexContext'
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <LaunchContextProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </LaunchContextProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Any suggestions on why this error is appearing and how to fix it?

Comment: this error seems to be caused by an export in your `index.js`. Are you exporting a react component as default in `index.js`?

Comment: `getStaticProps` will only work inside a `page` ie pages folder . It will not work outside that folder .